# LICENSE: command not found

Tags: xterm, license

All:   In Ubuntu 16.04, every time I open a terminal using icon or using xterm, it opens a terminal, but says

```
LICENSE: command not found
LICENSE: command not found
```

I am wondering why does it happen?  It was not there when I installed Ubuntu, but has recently started happening.  Since it is not stopping me from doing my work, I ignored it, but wonder what is the reason and it it may have an unintended consequence.

Thanks and appreciate in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common cause is the `~/.bashrc`. Some applications could modify it.

Use the next commands to find out where the wrong line exists:

```
grep -r LICENSE ~/*
sudo grep -r LICENSE /etc/*
```

Comment out that line using `#` before that line

Comment: Thank you, @Gyru.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to look into the .bashrc.   There was a MATLAB license file command in .bashrc, which was unable to locate the license.  I commented it out and the error was gone.   I am so glad that I asked this group.   Thanks again.